# Python countdown

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I currently took a snippet off the web that allows for 4 pictures to be taken with a camera. This works well.

I've then tried to take another snippet off the web that would count down before it takes a picture, this gave me great headache, and I'm wondering if someone much smarter can figer this out for me...

```
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0))
fontObj = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 100)
textSurfaceObj = fontObj.render("3", True, (255, 0, 0))
textRectObj = textSurfaceObj.get_rect()
textRectObj.center = (surface.get_width() / 2, surface.get_height() / 2)

def show_image(image_path):
    screen = init_pygame()
    img=pygame.image.load(image_path)
    img = pygame.transform.scale(img,(transform_x,transfrom_y))
    screen.blit(img,(offset_x,offset_y))
    pygame.display.flip()

    def init_pygame():
        pygame.init()
        size = (pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h)
        pygame.display.set_caption('Pictures')
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False) #hide the mouse cursor
        return pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.FULLSCREEN)

        print "Taking pics"
        now = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")
        try:
                for i, filename in enumerate(camera.capture_continuous(config.file_path + now + '-' + '{counter:02d}.jpg')):
                        print(filename)
                        for y in range(3,0,-1):
                                surface.fill((0,0,0,0))
                                textSurfaceObj = fontObj.render(str(y), True, (255, 0, 0))
                                surface.blit(textSurfaceObj, textRectObj)
                                pygame.display.update()
                                pygame.time.wait(1000)
                        sleep(capture_delay)
                        if i == total_pics-1:
                                break
        finally:
                camera.stop_preview()
                camera.close()
```

It returns me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pics.py", line 58, in <module>
    fontObj = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 100)
pygame.error: font not initialized
```

I was under the impression that if pygame.init() was done, fonts should be initialised?

Comment: did you try to call `pygame.font.init()`?

Comment: You have called neither `pygame.init()` nor `pygame.font.init()` before you try to use font.Font

Comment: try reading up on [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/intro/intro.html) and how to initialize it. you'll be amazed how smart you can get ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you invoke:

```
pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 100)
```

before you call:

```
pygame.init()
```

probably in line 58 of your file pics.py.You've provided the answer to your question yourself. You might be smarter than you think.